# How to insert prefix to all array elements but first and last?

Tags: ruby, string

How can I add a prefix to all array elements except the first and last ones?

Is there a one line solution to that? Or a 'nicer' solution than mine?

```
result = ["svn up", "20111128025010", "20111128025022", "pass"]
for i in 1..result.length-2
  result[i]=" - "+result[i]
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
result[1 ... -1].each { |s| s[0, 0] = ' - ' }
```

Note that there are three dots, not two. This works because `s[0,0]` modifies `s` in-place. If you're using 1.9.3+, you could also (and probably should) use [`prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-prepend):

```
result[1 ... -1].each { |s| s.prepend(' - ') }
```

And, as [the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man) notes in the comments, you could also use the double-dot range operator which is more common:

```
result[1 .. -2].each { |s| s[0, 0] = ' - ' }
result[1 .. -2].each { |s| s.prepend(' - ') }
```

Which range operator you use is a matter of preference.

Comment: I prefer seeing `1..-2` instead of `1...-1`. The three-dot range operator is easily missed in code, becoming a maintenance issue.

Comment: @theTinMan: This is one of the few places where I'd use a triple dot and I will admit that it is mostly for aesthetic reasons. I'm still debating how much whitespace should be around my range operators (`1...-1` vs `1 ... -1`), more space would help differentiate the double- and triple-dot versions.

Comment: I tend to use whitespace in range operations, or anyplace where it helps make it easier. The interpreter doesn't care at all, so it's a readability issue then.

Comment: @theTinMan: Yeah, I think I prefer the spaced versions of the range operators and it does help differentiate between `..` and `...`.

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible to do it like this:

```
result = ["svn up", "20111128025010", "20111128025022", "pass"]

result[1..-2].map { |s| s.insert(0, '-') }

p result #=> ["svn up", "-20111128025010", "-20111128025022", "pass"]
```

See [`ri String#insert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-insert)